# Redirecting http to https using ReWrite rule using AWS sends all requests to default webroot instead of using ProxyPass

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https

I have an Apache webserver running on an AWS EC2 instance on port 80.
I have an ELB with a certificate. All requests are intercepted by the ELB and forwarded to my EC2 instance, where my webserver listens for any calls.

When any http traffic comes, I redirect it to https using the rule given below which is present in my http-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

Now in my http-vhosts.conf, I redirect any traffic coming to port 443(which is the default https port) using proxypass as shown below:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now suppose I make a call to:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com
```

It is redirected to:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com
```

But this link now serves the index.html file present in my default webroot given in httpd.conf file, instead of redirecting it using ProxyPass.
Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are terminating SSL on the ELB, and the communication between ELB and EC2 is only on port 80, then your proxy configuration will never get invoked.

To fix this, you have two options:  The first one is to add the proxy config (the settings you have in the *:443 VirtualHost entry) to the *:80 entry.

The second option would be to add configure the ELB to talk to your EC2 instance on 443 as well as 80.  You will need to install & configure SSL and an appropriate cert (self-signed will do).

Comment: You are right. Figured it out eventually and was just about to answer for others. Have accepted the answer. Used the first option. Added the proxyconfig details to *:80 and it started working